# Why XCode needs to be stopped to update iTunes ?

Tags: itunes, xcode, software-update

I'm wondering everytime iTunes has an update :

Why XCode needs to be stopped to update iTunes ?

Is it some kind of shared component ?

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99472/is-it-possible-to-update-the-itunes-without-updating-xcode?rq=1 help?

Comment: It's a good start but lacks references imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both depend upon the same PrivateFramework.

Specifically `usbmuxd` is part of the MobileDevice.framework which communicates to iOS devices. When an iTunes update includes an update to `usbmuxd`, then Xcode can be flagged to prevent it from interacting with the subsystem while the update is being performed.